22.04 - No sound from internal speaker, XPS 13
hope someone can help troubleshoot this.
Some time ago (months!) the internal speaker stopped working. Audio through bluetooth, or cabled through the minijack output works well. Internal speaker mostly doesn't work, sometimes it magically does, but volume doesn't change, it's either full on or totally off.
It's a Dell XPS13 laptop, running Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.8.0.48
When running off a live USB, it works perfectly, so it's definitely not a hardware issue.
I've tried reinstalling pulseaudio and pipewire-media-session but didn't improve things.
Thanks in advance for any advice


I've tried reinstalling pulseaudio and pipewire-media-session but didn't improve things.


Since ubuntu 22.04.4, you are normally using pipewire:
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/pipewire
You should not install pulseaudio. Only:

pipewire-pulse, that is a compatibility layer
pavucontrol if you want, that is still the recommended tool to finely control audio interfaces.


pipewire-media-session is deprecated.
you can follow instrucitons there (best guide I found, in french, use your favorite translation engine):
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/pipewire#installer_le_gestionnaire_wireplumber_recommande


Hope this helps
